# JSON created by SQL cant be read in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, json

I'm creating a JSON-file in SQL, but the 'ROOT' is formatted the wrong way for use in javascript.

```
In Microsoft SQL server Management Studio 17.6:
select 
    a.Latitude Lat,
    a.Longitude Long
from
    Duurzamekaart.dbo.Poi a

FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('markers')
```

Results in:

```
{  
   "markers":[  
      {  
         "Lat":3.300000,
         "Long":3.400000
      },
      {  
         "Lat":4.400000,
         "Long":4.500000
      }
   ]
}
```

But javascript expects:

```
 markers = [  
      {  
         "Lat":3.300000,
         "Long":3.400000
      },
      {  
         "Lat":4.400000,
         "Long":4.500000
      }
   ]
```

How can I let SQL write in the correct format, or make javascript to see the markers as an array, so that i can use for example:

```
markers[i].Lat
```

The generated version throws two errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :      markers.json:1
kaart.js:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: markers is not defined
at kaart.js:41
```

The JSON file is not parsed but stored on disk and included in my HTML:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='json/markers.json'></script>
```

Comment: Neither of those examples are valid

Comment: The first one is valid json, the second isnt.

Comment: They are not valid when not closed properly. Anthony is correct.

Comment: JavaScript does not expect that...... The issue is probably how you are using it... Basically what you are saying is that the fundamental object in JavaScript is not readable.

Comment: Please provide a more complete example of the JSON that arrives at the browser.

Comment: markers = JSON.parse(jsontest).markers

Comment: Please read [How to create a complete, minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question accordingly. Please also indicate which flavor of SQL you're using.

Comment: I did put a stripped part of the SQL and JSON in the example.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your examples are incorrect JSON structures, you should start by reading this, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Note the second example:
**If you receive data in JSON format, you can convert it into a JavaScript object:**

```
var myJSON = '{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }';
var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
```

Comment: I'm not creating the JSON file myselve, but letting it auto create by MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the string into a JavaScript object:

```
var rawJson = '{ "markers": [ (etc...) ] }';
var markers = JSON.parse(rawJSON).markers;
```

Then you can use `markers` the way you described.